# Sugar orm can not find data from database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sugarorm

i'm using Sugar orm library in my android app. i'm facing with an issue that is when i open application **after a while**, it can not load data from database. of course i save the object when i receive data from server. here is my code , when i receive data from server and save it to database.

```
public static void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.user.save();
}
```

and this is my code when i want to get data from database, that can not find anything.

```
public static User getInstance(){
    User user = findById(User.class, (long) 1); // we've just one user using this app
    if (user != null) {
        return user;
    }else {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

please help me to solve this issue, thanks.

Comment: can you share the `User` class definition?

Comment: What error are you receiving back? Being unable to find any rows?